# Computer Vision: Simple Question - what are 'side lobes'?

Tags: computer-vision

This is a very trivial question!!

In some computer vision literature, side-lobes are mentioned.. what are they?.... Can't seem to find anywhere that actually says what they are :S.

Thanks :).

Comment: Does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_lobe help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a term from antenna theory. Antennas broadcast radiation (radio, microwave, light, infrared) in a certain pattern. Generally, there will be a preferred direction and most of the energy will be in that 'main lobe'. However, there generally exists secondary directions ('side lobes') of energy transmission. Some times, side lobes are a not ideal and are engineered to a minimum. Other times, side lobes can be an advantage and are enhanced.

Bob

Comment: Cheers Bob, brilliant answer :).

Answer (score 2):

[Did a quick google search](http://books.google.se/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA442&lpg=PA442&dq=side-lobes+computer+vision&source=bl&ots=hRM2dkdBTd&sig=E3u7LTXUcemcMnFfd3XSqGmsFLQ&hl=sv&ei=4lsPTc_3J8Ga8QPRscCGBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=side-lobes&f=false)

Byt it seams like the wiki page mentioned i also relevant along with

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage

I assume its a way of finding noice.